# ADODB Error inserting to Access DB with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ado, adodb

I am writing an .asp file to insert data to an Access database using the following JS:

```
    MM_query =  "INSERT " + 
                "INTO Employees (FirstName, Surname, Department, Email, FaxNumber, JobTitle, KnownAs, MobileTelephone, WorkTelephone, MUGSHOT, WorkExtension, UseInPhoneWeb, Staff, Office, MobileSpeedDial, CompanyID1) " +
                "VALUES (\"" + textFirstname + "\", \"" + textSurname + "\", \"" + selectDept + "\", \"" + textemailAddress + "\", \"" + textFaxTel + "\", \"" + textJobTitle + "\", \"" + textAKA + "\", \"" + textMobile + "\", \"" + textWorkNo + "\", \"" + selectMugShot + "\", \"" + textExtn + "\", 1, 1, \"" + selectOffice + "\", " + textMobSpDial + ", " + selectCompany + ")";

    var conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
    conn.Open(MM_PhoneWeb_conn_STRING);

    var rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rs.Open(MM_query, conn);

    conn.Close();
```

Upon execution I get the following error:

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
```

The query works when pasted directly to access and similar code works for retrieving data from the DB.

Can anyone suggest how best to troubleshoot?

Comment: I guess you need to put single quotes around the values.

Comment: Thanks Mairaj, I'd tried that initially but then later changed it to double quotes.

Comment: Also textFirstname looks to be name of textbox if it is textbox than you need to get text of this like `textFirstname.Text`

Comment: Nope, they're parameters... textFirstname = Request.QueryString("textFirstname");

Comment: Can u tell the detailed error ?

Comment: Detailed errors are enabled but all I get is: An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. 
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78999/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-bailz).

Comment: Why have you used slashes you can simply write the query like this `"INSERT " + 
                "INTO Employees (FirstName, Surname, Department, Email, FaxNumber, JobTitle, KnownAs, MobileTelephone, WorkTelephone, MUGSHOT, WorkExtension, UseInPhoneWeb, Staff, Office, MobileSpeedDial, CompanyID1) " +
                "VALUES ('" + textFirstname + "', '" + textSurname + "',........." `

Answer (score 0):

The account used by IIS to insert to the database had read-only permissions on the containing folder/DB.